# Increment element value using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Iam stuck in incrementing value using xslt. I need to Increment an element value based upon certain conditions.In Actual xml For Each policy/PolicyConditions met,i need to increment by one and create policy/PolicyConditions/PolicyConditionCriteria/ItemData .Please find the Expected xml for details.

Input XML:

```
    <buildings>
    <building>
                <building-header>
                    <location-number>LU1</location-number>
                    <building-number>LU1-B1</building-number>
                </building-header>
    </building> 
    <building>
                <building-header>
                    <location-number>LU2</location-number>
                    <building-number>LU2-B1</building-number>
                </building-header>
    </building>
    <building>
                <building-header>
                    <location-number>LU2</location-number>
                    <building-number>LU2-B2</building-number>
                </building-header>
    </building>
    <building>
                <building-header>
                    <location-number>LU3</location-number>
                    <building-number>LU3-B1</building-number>
                </building-header>
    </building>
    <building>
                <building-header>
                    <location-number>LU3</location-number>
                    <building-number>LU3-B2</building-number>
                </building-header>
    </building>
    <building>
                <building-header>
                    <location-number>LU4</location-number>
                    <building-number>LU4-B1</building-number>
                </building-header>
    </building>     
    <policy-details>
    <coverages>
    <coverage>
    <limit>
            <limit-type code="Bla"/>
    </limit>
    <location-rule>
                            <insured-objects>
                                <insured-object>
                                    <insured-object-nr>LU1</insured-object-nr>
                                </insured-object>
                                <insured-object>
                                    <insured-object-nr>LU2</insured-object-nr>
                                </insured-object>
                            </insured-objects>
    </location-rule>
    </coverage>
    <coverage>
    <limit>
            <limit-type code="Bla"/>
    </limit>
    <location-rule>
                            <insured-objects>
                                <insured-object>
                                    <insured-object-nr>LU3</insured-object-nr>
                                </insured-object>
                            </insured-objects>
    </location-rule>
    </coverage>
    <coverage>
    <limit>
            <limit-type code="Sub"/>
    </limit>
    <location-rule>
                            <insured-objects>
                                <insured-object>
                                    <insured-object-nr>LU2</insured-object-nr>
                                </insured-object>
                                <insured-object>
                                    <insured-object-nr>LU3</insured-object-nr>
                                </insured-object>
                            </insured-objects>
    </location-rule>
    </coverage>
    </coverages>
    </policy-details>
    </buildings>
```

XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>



    <xsl:template match="/">
        <policy>
            <xsl:for-each select="//coverage">
                <xsl:if test="limit/limit-type/@code='Bla'">
                    <PolicyConditions>
                        <Name>EQ Blanket</Name>
                        <xsl:for-each select="location-rule/insured-objects/insured-object">
                            <xsl:variable name="var_Ins_Obj">
                                <xsl:value-of select="insured-object-nr"/>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:for-each select="//building">
                                <xsl:variable name="var_loc_Num">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="building-header/location-number"/>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:if test="$var_loc_Num=$var_Ins_Obj">
                                    <xsl:variable name="locBuild">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="building-header/building-number"/>
                                    </xsl:variable>
                                    <PolicyConditionCriteria>
                                        <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
                                        <Value>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$locBuild"/>
                                        </Value>
                                    </PolicyConditionCriteria>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </PolicyConditions>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="limit/limit-type/@code='Sub'">
                    <PolicyConditions>
                        <Name>EQ Sublimit</Name>
                        <xsl:for-each select="location-rule/insured-objects/insured-object">
                            <xsl:variable name="var_Ins_Obj">
                                <xsl:value-of select="insured-object-nr"/>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:for-each select="//building">
                                <xsl:variable name="var_loc_Num">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="building-header/location-number"/>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:if test="$var_loc_Num=$var_Ins_Obj">
                                    <xsl:variable name="locBuild">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="building-header/building-number"/>
                                    </xsl:variable>
                                    <PolicyConditionCriteria>
                                        <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
                                        <Value>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="$locBuild"/>
                                        </Value>
                                    </PolicyConditionCriteria>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </PolicyConditions>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>

        </policy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actual XML:

```
    <policy>
       <PolicyConditions>
          <Name>EQ Blanket</Name>
          <PolicyConditionCriteria>
             <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
             <Value>LU1-B1</Value>
          </PolicyConditionCriteria>
          <PolicyConditionCriteria>
             <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
             <Value>LU2-B1</Value>
          </PolicyConditionCriteria>
          <PolicyConditionCriteria>
             <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
             <Value>LU2-B2</Value>
          </PolicyConditionCriteria>
       </PolicyConditions>
       <PolicyConditions>
          <Name>EQ Blanket</Name>
          <PolicyConditionCriteria>
             <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
             <Value>LU3-B1</Value>
          </PolicyConditionCriteria>
          <PolicyConditionCriteria>
             <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
             <Value>LU3-B2</Value>
          </PolicyConditionCriteria>
       </PolicyConditions>
       <PolicyConditions>
          <Name>EQ Sublimit</Name>
          <PolicyConditionCriteria>
             <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
             <Value>LU2-B1</Value>
          </PolicyConditionCriteria>
          <PolicyConditionCriteria>
             <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
             <Value>LU2-B2</Value>
          </PolicyConditionCriteria>
          <PolicyConditionCriteria>
             <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
             <Value>LU3-B1</Value>
          </PolicyConditionCriteria>
          <PolicyConditionCriteria>
             <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
             <Value>LU3-B2</Value>
          </PolicyConditionCriteria>
       </PolicyConditions>
    </policy>
```

Expected XML:

```
<policy>
       <PolicyConditions>
          <Name>EQ Blanket1</Name>
          <Item>1</Item>
          <PolicyConditionCriteria>
             <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
             <Value>LU1-B1</Value>
             <ItemData>1</ItemData>
          </PolicyConditionCriteria>
          <PolicyConditionCriteria>
             <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
             <Value>LU2-B1</Value>
             <ItemData>2</ItemData>
          </PolicyConditionCriteria>
          <PolicyConditionCriteria>
             <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
             <Value>LU2-B2</Value>
             <ItemData>3</ItemData>
          </PolicyConditionCriteria>
       </PolicyConditions>
       <PolicyConditions>
          <Name>EQ Blanket2</Name>
          <Item>2</Item>
          <PolicyConditionCriteria>
             <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
             <Value>LU3-B1</Value>
             <ItemData>1</ItemData>
          </PolicyConditionCriteria>
          <PolicyConditionCriteria>
             <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
             <Value>LU3-B2</Value>
             <ItemData>2</ItemData>
          </PolicyConditionCriteria>
       </PolicyConditions>
       <PolicyConditions>
          <Name>EQ Sublimit1</Name>
          <Item>2</Item>
          <PolicyConditionCriteria>
             <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
             <Value>LU2-B1</Value>
             <ItemData>1</ItemData>
          </PolicyConditionCriteria>
          <PolicyConditionCriteria>
             <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
             <Value>LU2-B2</Value>
             <ItemData>2</ItemData>
          </PolicyConditionCriteria>
          <PolicyConditionCriteria>
             <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
             <Value>LU3-B1</Value>
              <ItemData>3</ItemData>
          </PolicyConditionCriteria>
          <PolicyConditionCriteria>
             <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
             <Value>LU3-B2</Value>
             <ItemData>4</ItemData>
          </PolicyConditionCriteria>
       </PolicyConditions>
    </policy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may benefit from using a key here to look up `building` elements by their `location-number`

```
<xsl:key name="buildings" match="building" use="building-header/location-number" />
```

Now, you can use `position()` to generate the number you want, but for this to be effective you would have to select the `building` elements for all `insured-object` within a coverage in one select statement.

```
 <xsl:variable name="insured-objects" select="location-rule/insured-objects/insured-object/insured-object-nr" />
 <xsl:for-each select="key('buildings', $insured-objects)">
```

I also noticed that there seems to be a lot of repetition in your XSLT, when the only difference between the two `xsl:if` statements seem to be generating the `Name` element.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="buildings" match="building" use="building-header/location-number" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <policy>
        <xsl:for-each select="//coverage">
            <PolicyConditions>
                <xsl:variable name="code" select="limit/limit-type/@code" />
                <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(preceding-sibling::coverage[limit/limit-type/@code = $code]) + 1" />
                <Name>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$code='Bla'">EQ Blanket</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$code='Sub'">EQ Sublimit</xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$count" />
                </Name>
                <Item>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$count" />
                </Item>
                <xsl:variable name="insured-objects" select="location-rule/insured-objects/insured-object/insured-object-nr" />
                <xsl:for-each select="key('buildings', $insured-objects)">
                    <PolicyConditionCriteria>
                        <Field>LOCNAME</Field>
                        <Value>
                            <xsl:value-of select="building-header/building-number"/>
                        </Value>
                        <ItemData>
                            <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                        </ItemData>
                    </PolicyConditionCriteria>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </PolicyConditions>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </policy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Dear Tim,Thanks a lot for your reply.I also have one more requirement to increment the number and append it with the hardcoded value of policy/PolicyConditions/Nqme, if it is of same limit/limit-type/@code.and one more element Item with the inremented value,I have changed the expected xml.Can you please through some lights on that as well,it would be helpful.

Comment: @Ravi - I have amended my answer to give the output you have shown.